# Sorting on one attribute removes another attribute from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I want sort the xml data based on count attribute and select first 100 values.

I have written this xsl. But it is removing @code from indicator tag which is required for further processing.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:if test="//field
                [count(indicators/indicator/values) &lt; '100' 
                or 
                count(subfields/subfield/position/values) &lt; '100'
                ]">
    <xsl:copy>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:sort select="@count" 
                  data-type="number" 
                  order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Please help to find 100 highest values and @code attribute which is removed after sorting from indicator tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not modify the identity transform. It is better to leave that template intact and write others as you need them: One to match the `position` element (to be able to sort its child elements):

```
<xsl:template match="position">
```

and another one that matches `values` elements if their position exceeds 100:

```
<xsl:template match="position/values[position() gt 100]"/>
```

I assume that by "sorting XML data" you meant sorting the `values` elements inside `position`. Also, I think by "select first 100 values" you meant selecting the first 100 `values` elements inside `position`.

**Stylesheet (XSLT 2.0)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="position">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:sort select="@count" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="indicator/values[position() gt 100]|position/values[position() gt 100]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

The stylesheet assumes that there are `values` elements other than the ones inside `indicator` and `position`. If this is not the case, the following template will do:

```
<xsl:template match="values[position() gt 100]"/>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<field count="3159" tag="461">
   <indicators>
      <indicator code="1">
         <values count="3159" value=" "/>
      </indicator>
      <indicator code="2">
         <values count="3159" value="1"/>
      </indicator>
   </indicators>
   <subfields>
      <subfield code="3" count="3497">
         <position>
            <values count="32" value="200000190420020805152452"/>
            <values count="28" value="200000000220020805151840"/>
            <values count="9" value="200000190720020805152453"/>
            <values count="8" value="200000190520020805152453"/>
            <values count="6" value="200000190820020805152454"/>
            <values count="3" value="200000190920020805152454"/>
            <values count="1" value="200000000120020805151840"/>
            <values count="1" value="200000190620020805152453"/>
         </position>
      </subfield>
   </subfields>
</field>
```

Note: A more reasonable input XML would of course contain more than 100 `values` elements to test whether they are sent to output or not.